# JavaScript - "Identifier has already been declared"

Tags: javascript, html

Having an issue with getting a register/ login form to work on HTML using localStorage. As part of my assignment, I cannot use databases or php even though these are easier. Specifically the issue is occurring during my submit function.

The syntax error coming back is "Identifier registerUser has already been declared", and highlights `const reponse = processUser (username.value, password.value)` in the console.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
//setup form
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setupForm);

function setupForm() {
    const form = document.getElementById("login");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}

//handle Submit
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {
        Username,
        Password,
        login_type,
        result
    } = event.target;

    const processUser = login_type.value == "register" ? registerUser : loginUser;
    const response = processUser(username.value, password.value);
    result.innerHTML = response;
}

//register new user
function registerUser(username, password) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    window.localStorage.setItem("password", password);

    return 'New user ${username} now registered!';
}

//login existing user
function loginUser(username, password) {
    const registeredUser = window.localStorage.getItem("username", username);
    const registeredUser = window.localStorage.getItem("password", password);

    const validUser = username == registeredUser;
    const validPassword = password == registeredUser;

    if (validUser && validPassword) {
        return 'User ${username} successfully logged-in!';
    }
    //error form for incorrect username or password
    else if (!validUser) return 'Incorrect username or password';
}
```

HTML form:

```
<fieldset>
    <form id="login" action="submit" method="post">
        <legend><b>Login here!</b></legend><br />
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" required />
        </div>
</fieldset>
<span>
    <input id="login" type="hidden" name="login_type" value="login" checked="checked"></input>
    <!--Hidden for the purposes of my script working-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br /><br />
    <output name="result"></output>
    </fieldset>
</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is very frustrating!

Comment: Is there more JS code?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, please share more JS code

Comment: Added the complete JS code

Comment: Could you please indent the code properly? It's very hard to read.

Comment: The error message seems to be pointing to the wrong line, for some reason. It should point out the duplicate `const registeredUser        =`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 variables have the same name already `registeredUser`.

```
const registeredUser        = window.localStorage.getItem("username", 
username);
const registeredUser        = window.localStorage.getItem("password", 
password);
```

So rather than try to use `registeredUser`, i've changed it to registeredPassword

```
//login existing user
function loginUser(username, password){

const registeredUser        = window.localStorage.getItem("username", 
username);

const registeredPassword      = window.localStorage.getItem("password", 
password);

const validUser                 = username === registeredUser;
const validPassword         = password === registeredPassword;
```

Also use`===` instead of `==` [reasons why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

you declared the identifier two times:

```
const registeredUser        = window.localStorage.getItem("username", 
username);
const registeredUser        = window.localStorage.getItem("password", 
password);
```