# Getting error 'commandFiles' has already been declared

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making an image bot for Discord servers but there's another problem:

> 'commandFiles' has already been declared.

Someone from here fixed it but not fully because a new problem came out. That's all of the script that is used for the image command, all the other stuff are just commands that have nothing to do with this and don't use 'commandFiles' in them.

Here's all of the script:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
    if (command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    }
    if (command == 'instagram'){
        client.commands.get('instagram').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('message', message => {
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
 
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'image':
        image(message);
 
        break;
    }
 
});

function image(message){
 
    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "cursed images",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
        }
    }};

    client.on('ready', () =>{
        console.log('This bot is online!');
    })

    request(options, function(error, response, responseBody){
        if (error){
            return;
        }
 
 
        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);
 
 
        var links = $(".image a.link");
 
        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
       
        console.log(urls);
 
        if (!urls.length) {
           
            return;
        }
 
        // Send result
        message.channel.send( urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
    });
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: look somewhere in your code you already declared commandFiles as a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - "Identifier has already been declared"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591189/javascript-identifier-has-already-been-declared)

Answer (score 1):

All this error means is that the variable `commandFiles` has already been defined somewhere else in your code.

For example:

```js
const commandFiles = 'foo';
const commandFiles = 'bar';

console.log(commandFiles);
```

JavaScript doesn't know which to use. I suggest searching for `commandFiles` and checking if there are more than one definition in your code.