# In JavaScript, what does "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'X' has already been declared" mean?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have written whilst doing an online course. When I go to inspect mode on Chrome it shows the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'country' has already been declared

How can I fix it?

```
let continent = 'Europe';
let population = 1300;
console.log(country);
console.log(continent);
console.log(population);

let isIsland = false;
let language;
console.log(typeof isIsland);
console.log(typeof population);
console.log(typeof country);
console.log(typeof language);

language = 'Dutch';
const country = 'Netherlands';
const continent = 'Europe';
const isIsland = false;
isIsland = true;

console.log(population / 2);
population++;
console.log(population);
console.log(population > 6);
console.log(population < 33);
const description1 = country + 'is in' + continent + ', and its' + population + 'million people speak' + language;
console.log(description1);
```

Comment: refresh tab and try again.

Comment: Do you by chance have a duplicate declaration of `country` above the line `let continent = 'Europe';`?

Comment: When running some code in "inspect mode" (via the console), the globally declared variables are kept nevertheless you'd run the same code again. You can't redefine a constant, hence the errror.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - "Identifier has already been declared"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591189/javascript-identifier-has-already-been-declared)

Answer (score 1):

there is a conflict with your variables declaration.

Wheter you use `let` or `var` will just influence their scope, but in your case, you can use both. So your delarations with let are fine.

But, latter in the code, you're using constants with theses `const`, and it means you can't modify theses.

At the line `const continent = 'Europe'`, you're in conflict with your first line of code `let continent = 'Europe'`.

So I suggest you either use only variables everywhere, so it's easy to modify them on the go, or your can define a couple on constants if you need to, and then use them in the code.